# Is it impossible to use the Automated Anchor Tags if recipient info (signer) are not provided before creating envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the Embedded Sending View so that a user can finish a DocuSign Envelope with their taste and send it. What I am doing only before opening the Embedded Sender View is to upload documents that they want to DocuSign through REST API and don't set any recipient info at all. Some uploading documents have anchor tags like \s1\, \s2\, and so on. For recipients, signer or cc, a user provides it when they are in the Embedded Sender View.

**What I would like to do is to show documents with anchor tags replaced with Sign tab when a user moves to the Tagging view using the recipients who a user provided in the Embedded Sender View, not pre-defined signer info.**

From my tests, it seems that anchor tags like \s1\ are never replaced with the Sign Here tab automatically if there is no signer information provided in the envelope definition before creating an envelope. When I created signer object and set only recipient ID to it, it works with only \s1\. It seems to me that the Signer has to be provided in order to use the AutoPlace feature before creating an envelope.

The following code is what I used for testing. When I provided the signer explicitly, the AutoPlace feature works only with the anchor tag for Signer 1, \s1\

```java
        ...
        EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        envelopeDefinition.setEmailSubject("Please sign this document");

        envelopeDefinition.setEmailBlurb("Something");

        Document doc1 = new Document();
        doc1.setDocumentBase64(new String(Base64.encode(DSHelper.readContent("Sign here.docx"))));
        doc1.setName("Sign Here Test");
        doc1.setFileExtension("docx");
        doc1.setDocumentId("1");

        // The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
        envelopeDefinition.setDocuments(Arrays.asList(doc1));

        //When I provided the signer explicitly, 
        //the AutoPlace feature works only with the anchor tag for Signer 1, \s1\\
        //Otherwise, it doesn't work at all
        Signer signer1 = new Signer();
        signer1.setRecipientId("1");  //This is mandatory 

        // Add the recipients to the envelope object
        Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
        recipients.setSigners(Arrays.asList(signer1));

        envelopeDefinition.setRecipients(recipients);        

        // create a signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
        // We're setting the parameters via the object creation
        EnvelopesApi envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi(this.apiClient);
        EnvelopeSummary results = envelopeApi.createEnvelope(this.getAccountId(), envelopeDefinition);

        //Generate Embedded Sender View URL....and so on
        ...
```

**UPDATE**
I provided the two recipients in the Embedded Sending View as you can see the below image, but only one \s1\ tag was replaced with Sign Here in the Tagging View after clicking the Next on the Embedded Sending View.

[This is the Embedded Sending View using the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdKNd.png)

[This is the document preview with above code's result on the Tagging View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSjhN.png)

Is there the best way to achieve my case?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're creating the envelope as a draft anyway, you don't actually need to define the second signer's Name and Email. When the Sender accesses the envelope, they can fill in the empty name & email and it will be associated with the tags the integration has already placed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added one more picture to my original question above. I provided the two recipients info in the Embedded Sending View as you can see the link "This the Embedded Sending View using the above code," but only one \s1\ tag was replaced with Sign Here in the Tagging View. The anchor tags \s2\ was not replaced with Sign Here tab.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to use a template. Templates can have placeholders which do not have the recipient information but allow you to have tags for these eventual recipients. 
You can create the envelope from your template at which point you have to provide actual recipient information (name and email).

Comment: [This code example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-create-template) shows how to programmatically create a template.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I considered using the Template feature. However, as far as I know, the Template feature is for a standard document. So in my case, I don't think that we can make templates for them because there are a lot of various types of documents created by a user. I don't know how many of them are and how many anchor tags are in the documents. I only know they will use automated anchor tags like \s1\, \s2\, \s3\.

Comment: Kangil, it's possible to replace the document of the template programatically and still use a template that just defines the recipients and tags. This may or may not be what you want but it's possible.

Comment: @InbarGazit Thank you. I forgot to mention that I cannot know how many signers will be filled in the recipient part of your DocuSign Sender View(=DocuSign Web Console(?)). Before defining the template, I think I have to know how many recipients will be there first in order to use the Automated Anchor Text feature. As I mentioned earlier, I cannot know it. That's why I left the comment that I don't think that I cannot use the template.

Comment: And if a user deletes an input form for the recipient on the Embedded Sending View, then hidden fields on input forms for recipients like "recipient ID"  will be deleted together, which a user cannot create it through the Embedded Sending View.

Comment: @KangilLee you may want to look into "Editor" recipients as a potential solution https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#editors-recipient these recipients can edit the recipients and change them after the envelope is already on route

Comment: another approach you may want to consider is using the "Correct" functionality if you ready this https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W000069k7NQSAY/is-it-possible-to-correct-an-envelope-already-sent-using-rest-api but again, not sure that's what you want exactly

Comment: @InbarGazit Thank for all your help. But the above solutions are not what I am looking for. I think the question in this post is unclear. I re-posted the same question but short version.